# How to use Numba to vectorize a function that takes scalars and returns a vector?

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, vectorization, numba

I have a function that takes two scalars and returns a 1-D array. Take for example:

```
import numpy as np
def linear_pattern(slope,length):
    pattern = slope*np.arange(length)
    return pattern
```

My goal is to be able of doing many `slope` at a time always for the same scalar value `length`, i.e., I would like to run

```
>>> linear_pattern(np.array([3,4]),10)
array([[ 0.,  3.,  6.,  9., 12., 15., 18., 21., 24., 27.],
       [ 0.,  4.,  8., 12., 16., 20., 24., 28., 32., 36.]])
```

instead of

```
>>> linear_pattern(3,10)
array([ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27])
>>> linear_pattern(4,10)
array([ 0,  4,  8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36])
```

I am using the decorator [`guvectorize`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/vectorize.html#the-guvectorize-decorator) from Numba to do the job. The following is my implementation:

```
from numba import float64, guvectorize
@guvectorize( [(float64, float64, float64[:])], '(),() -> (n)' )
def linear_pattern(slope,length,pattern):
    pattern[:] = slope*np.arange(length)
```

However, I get an error when I try to run the following example:

```
>>> pattern = np.zeros(10) 
>>> linear_pattern(np.array([3,4]),10,pattern)
NameError: undefined output symbols: n
```

**The error complains because I set the function's output to be a vector of dimension `n` and such dimension is not defined, i.e., I did not use `n` anywhere in the input dimensions. However, the inputs are all scalars which precludes the use of `n`.**

My questions are:

1. how can I make the above code work?
2. since `length` is always the same scalar, I would prefer it to be a *kwarg* of `linear_pattern` instead of a *arg*, however, the decorator `guvectorize` seems not to accept functions with *kwarg*-type arguments. Can `guvectorize` accept *kwarg* arguments?

---

Temporarily, I got the code to work by defining a dummy variable `_` with the same dimension as the output. See below:

```
length = 10
__ = np.zeros(length)

@guvectorize( [(float64, float64, float64[:], float64[:])], '(),(),(n) -> (n)' )
def linear_pattern(slope,length,__,pattern):
    pattern[:] = slope*np.arange(length)

>>> pattern = np.zeros(length) 
>>> linear_pattern(np.array([3,4]),length,pattern)
array([[ 0.,  3.,  6.,  9., 12., 15., 18., 21., 24., 27.],
       [ 0.,  4.,  8., 12., 16., 20., 24., 28., 32., 36.]])
```

---

**Edit 1:**

In my original question, I used a simplified version of the actual function I need to vectorize. The original one has more arguments which also need to respond to vectorization.

Take for instance the modified function below

```
def linear_pattern(slope, intercept, length):
pattern = slope*np.arange(length) + intercept
return pattern
```

I would like then to run

```
slopes = np.array([3, 4])
intercepts = np.array([0, 1, 2])
length = 10
linear_pattern(slopes, intercepts, length)
```

and that the result have dimension `(len(slopes),len(intercepts),length)` which, in this case, is `(2,3,10)`. Note that `length` will always be a fix integer and there is no need for vectorization on that argument, in fact, the ideal solution will keep `length` as a *kwarg*-type argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind `linear_pattern` returning a matrix, you could use NumPy's broadcasting (no Numba required):

```
import numpy as np

def linear_pattern(slope,length):
    pattern = slope * np.arange(length).reshape((1, -1))
    return pattern

print(linear_pattern(3, 10))
print(linear_pattern(np.array([[3], [4]]), 10))
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27]]
[[ 0  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27]
 [ 0  4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36]]
```

### How this works

1. `np.arange(10).reshape((1, -1))` is `array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])`
2. Element-wise (!) multiplication of this by `np.array([[3], [4]])` looks like this:

```
3                    3 * [0 1 2 3 ...]      [0 3 6  9 ...]
  * [0 1 2 3 ...] =                       = 
4                    4 * [0 1 2 3 ...]      [0 4 8 12 ...]
```

Comment: I do not mind `linear_pattern` returning a matrix. However, I will need to apply the vectorization to a function that has more than one argument that need to accept vectorization. See the **Edit 1** in my question. I tried to use ` .reshape((1, -1))` in the modified form of `linear_pattern` in **Edit 1** however I did not get the desired result. I think that using Numba the vectorization could be extended to as many arguments as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use Numba, temporary solutions live for a very long time. As a matter of fact, the use of dummy inputs is the way to go because, according to the [docs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/vectorize.html#the-guvectorize-decorator), the output *array is actually allocated by NumPy’s dispatch mechanism, which calls into the Numba-generated code*.

Now that you need to allocate a dummy input, the `length` parameter is redundant. Instead, you could allocate the full output:

```
@nb.guvectorize([(nb.float64, nb.float64[:], nb.float64[:])], '(),(n) -> (n)')
def linear_pattern2(slope, __, pattern):
    pattern[:] = slope * np.arange(len(pattern))

>>> pattern = np.empty((2, length))
>>> linear_pattern2(np.array([3, 4]), pattern2)
array([[ 0.,  3.,  6.,  9., 12., 15., 18., 21., 24., 27.],
       [ 0.,  4.,  8., 12., 16., 20., 24., 28., 32., 36.]])
```

And you can prevent the unnecessary allocation of the output array using the `out` *kwarg* (automagically provided by Numpy's *ufunc* specification) which may be relevant for large arrays:

```
>>> pattern = np.empty((2, length))
>>> linear_pattern2(np.array([3, 4]), pattern, out=pattern)
>>> pattern
array([[ 0.,  3.,  6.,  9., 12., 15., 18., 21., 24., 27.],
       [ 0.,  4.,  8., 12., 16., 20., 24., 28., 32., 36.]])
```

The function's return and the input array are the same object:

```
>>> pattern = np.empty((2, length))
>>> lp = linear_pattern2(np.array([3, 4]), pattern, out=pattern)
>>> lp is pattern
True
```